# How to retrieve values from a certain key from several dicts inside 1 dict?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a problem getting certain values from a dict that contains several other dicts. It looks like this:

```
dictionary = {
    '1532': {'text': 'Hello World, nice day huh?',
             'user': 'some_name',
             'word_list': ['Hello', 'World', 'nice', 'day', 'huh']},
    '4952': {'text': "It's a beautiful day",
             'user': 'some_name',
             'word_list': ["It's", 'a', 'beautiful', 'day']},
    '7125': {'text': 'I have a problem',
             'user': 'some_name',
             'word_list': ['I', 'have', 'a', 'problem']}}
```

What I want to do is iterate over the dictionary and with each iteration only retrieve the value of 'word_list'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just iterate over the values of `dictionary` then:

```
for sub in dictionary.values():
    print(sub['word_list'])
```

If this is Python 2, consider using `dictionary.itervalues()` so you don't build up a new list object for the loop.

This produces:

```
>>> for sub in dictionary.values():
...     print(sub['word_list'])
... 
["It's", 'a', 'beautiful', 'day']
['I', 'have', 'a', 'problem']
['Hello', 'World', 'nice', 'day', 'huh']
```

You can of course nest the looping; you can further loop over the word list:

```
for sub in dictionary.values():
    for word in sub['word_list']:
        print(word)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a very basic approach:

```
for x in dictionary.values():
  print x["word_list"]
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach using `pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd

pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dictionary, orient='index').word_list.tolist()

Out[407]:
[['Hello', 'World', 'nice', 'day', 'huh'],
 ["It's", 'a', 'beautiful', 'day'],
 ['I', 'have', 'a', 'problem']]
```

If you want to have the words in a single list:

```
from itertools import chain
import pandas as pd

list(chain(*pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dictionary, orient='index').word_list))

Out[410]:
['Hello',
 'World',
 'nice',
 'day',
 'huh',
 "It's",
 'a',
 'beautiful',
 'day',
 'I',
 'have',
 'a',
 'problem']
```